# PHP create html pages with images for download without saving on server

Tags: php, forms, file-upload, download

I'd like to know if it is possible to generate a downloadable html page from users input and upload without saving anything on the server.The html form would allow users to download a website (with images) from the submit button.

I figured putting all the html, css, and javascript into an html file and then **echo** it like the code below, would do the trick. But when it gets to the images, I am not sure how to handle them without having to create a zip folder on the server that would contain images and the html page.

```
<?php
  $htmlcode1 = "<HTML> \n <BODY>";
  $htmlcode2 = "</BODY> \n <HTML>";
  $htmlcontent = "";
  $postedname = $_POST["tofile"];
  $fileContent = $htmlcode1.$_POST["tofile"].$htmlcode2;    
  header("Content-Type: text/html" );
  header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$postedname.".html"); 
  echo $fileContent;
?>
```

Comment: You could look in to MHTML -- a single source (images included) file.

Comment: `<img alt="Embedded Image" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAADIA..." />`